# How do you roll back (reset) a Git repository to a particular commit?

Tags: git

I cloned a Git repository and then tried to roll it back to a particular commit early on in the development process. Everything that was added to the repository after that point is unimportant to me so I want to omit all subsequent changes from my local source code.

However, when I try to roll back in the GUI tool it doesn't update my local file system - I always end up with the latest source code for the project.

What's the correct way to just get the source for a repository as of a particular commit in the project's history and omit all later updates?

Comment: git reset --hard aabb3434 / git push origin branch --force

Comment: The most useful questions on stackoverflow are the ones most likely to be closed for being a duplicate

Answer (score 1273, accepted):

```
git reset --hard <tag/branch/commit id>
```

---

***Notes:***

- `git reset` without the `--hard` option resets the commit history, but not the files. With the `--hard` option the files in working tree are also reset. ([credited user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/964/kauppi))
- If you wish to commit that state so that the remote repository also points to the rolled back commit do: `git push <reponame> -f` ([credited user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/96806/mariusz-nowak))

Comment: @MariuszNowak after doing git reset --hard <commit-id>, ( 2 back ) when doing "git push -f origin master" I get "remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/master (you should pull first)" it is my repo and I want to take it back :)

Comment: @peterk try `--force` at the end of your git push command

Comment: Make sure you specify the branch name as well.

Comment: In server end there is a configuration option for the repository if non-fast-forward pushes are allowed with --force. man git-config and check .git/config for denyNonFastForwards = true in repository.

Comment: This doesn't actually work: `fatal: Cannot do hard reset with paths.`

Comment: The second option for me did not run: I had to do `git push -f <remoterepo> master` to restore the remote repository too. However, be aware that with the `-f` switch the commits after the restored commit are also ***LOST*** on the remote repo! (this is what I wanted but someone else may wish to preserve history).

Comment: Hey @kauppi can you please include branchname in git push <reponame> -f command in your answer?

Comment: if your are doing "git reset --hard c9kid83", and want to push changes to same branch run "git push -f", it will also rest your history

Comment: they thx for your answers: anyone know if: git reset HEAD~2 is different to git reset Head~2 --hard?

Comment: git reset --hard <commit-id> is what worked for me

Comment: You say "If you wish to **commit** that state you need to ... **push**" - I just have a local repository, so push is not an option. How should that work?

Comment: This way does not work for me. remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/master (you should pull first)

Comment: Is this also possible without using `--force`? You don't always have the possibility to overwrite the history.

Comment: Would I permanently loose my newer commits?

Answer (score 427):

### Update:

Because of changes to how tracking branches are created and pushed I no longer recommend renaming branches. This is what I recommend now:

Make a copy of the branch at its current state:

```
git branch crazyexperiment
```

(The [`git branch <name>`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) command will leave you with your current branch still checked out.)

Reset your current branch to your desired commit with [`git reset`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset):

```
git reset --hard c2e7af2b51
```

(Replace `c2e7af2b51` with the commit that you want to go back to.)

When you decide that your crazy experiment branch doesn't contain anything useful, you can delete it with:

```
git branch -D crazyexperiment
```

It's always nice when you're starting out with history-modifying git commands (reset, rebase) to create backup branches before you run them. Eventually once you're comfortable you won't find it necessary. If you do modify your history in a way that you don't want and haven't created a backup branch, look into [`git reflog`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog). Git keeps commits around for quite a while even if there are no branches or tags pointing to them.

### Original answer:

A slightly less scary way to do this than the `git reset --hard` method is to create a new branch. Let's assume that you're on the `master` branch and the commit you want to go back to is `c2e7af2b51`.

Rename your current master branch:

```
git branch -m crazyexperiment
```

Check out your good commit:

```
git checkout c2e7af2b51
```

Make your new master branch here:

```
git checkout -b master
```

Now you still have your crazy experiment around if you want to look at it later, but your master branch is back at your last known good point, ready to be added to. If you really want to throw away your experiment, you can use:

```
git branch -D crazyexperiment
```

Comment: Thanks - might not have been what the poster asked for, but much less anxiety-inducing for me.

Comment: Dealing with a remote repository (such as Github), you may have to do a 'git push -f origin master' because of the non-fastforwards to get master to look like it did at the specified commit, but this method is much cleaner than reset.

Comment: git reset --hard is not that particularly dirty. It is introduced in nearly every git tutorial available as the proper method to undo changes in your own tree. If not in basic features, at least in intermediate ones.

If you somehow get into an unknown state/HEAD, there's always git reflog which tells the history of HEAD regardless of branches. Pick a proper commitid from there, and branch from it or git reset --hard with that.

Comment: kauppi - wouldnt you then have issues pushing back to a remote repo?

Comment: Reflog is nice when you reset to an earlier commit but then can't find your previous HEAD SHA.

Comment: One more thing: if your old master branch (now renamed to crazyexperiment) was tracking a remote branch, what will happen after the steps in this answer are that crazyexperiment will be tracking that remote branch, and master will not be tracking anything. You might need `git branch --set-upstream-to=<remote>/<branch> master` and `git branch --set-upstream-to=<remote>/<branch> crazyexperiment` to set those up appropriately

Comment: Oops, that should be `git branch --set-upstream master <remote>/<branch>` and `git branch --set-upstream crazyexperiment <remote>/<branch>`

Comment: I followed the instructions here and after doing `git branch -D crazyexperiment` I permanently deleted all my code.  I was expecting to get back to the original state, i.e. the state before doing `reset`  Posting the commands necessary to restore the backup would be helpful.

Comment: +1 for the crazyexperiment, it works without dirtying up the rest of the commits and it's easy to delete the Frankenstein branch

Comment: I did all of this. But how can I merge crazymaster with master branch since technically I don't have any changes? Correct me if i'm wrong but we can only create pull requests if we have any changes, right?

Answer (score 14):

For those with a git gui bent, you can also use gitk.

Right click on the commit you want to return to and select "Reset master branch to here". Then choose hard from the next menu.

Comment: no workee when server (stash) disallows force on push. Cannot reset back there.

Comment: git hard reset "enter commit id here" : It will roll back to you till that stage

Answer (score 1):

When you say the 'GUI Tool', I assume you're using Git For Windows.

IMPORTANT, I would highly recommend creating a new branch to do this on if you haven't already. That way your master can remain the same while you test out your changes.

With the GUI you need to 'roll back this commit' like you have with the history on the right of your view. Then you will notice you have all the unwanted files as changes to commit on the left.
Now you need to right click on the grey title above all the uncommited files and select 'disregard changes'. This will set your files back to how they were in this version.