# How do I revert git code base to a certain revision

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you roll back (reset) a git repository to a particular commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616957/how-do-you-roll-back-reset-a-git-repository-to-a-particular-commit)

I have the following revisions in order `r1, r2, r3, r4, r5 in origin/master`.

1. How do I revert the entire code base to a previous snapshot in a certain branch (say `r3`)
2. If I do [1], will subsequent commits say `r4', r5'` be on top of `r3` and we will not have any reference to `r4, r5` in the code base.

Comment: This offers a possible solution without losing the reference to r4, r5. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1625275/277923

Comment: How will this work if r4, r5 are already there in the git repository.

Comment: @priya, this creates a new branch, which leaves r4, r5 intact while r4' and r5' are committed on the new branch. This way, you can revert to the current branch, if required.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs How do you make r3 as the HEAD post checkout, so that future check-ins go on top of this and not r5

Comment: @priya Well, I guess you need to create a branch then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `git reset --hard r3` will revert your currently checked out branch back to `r3`.
2. Subsequent commits will be on top of `r3`. You will lose any reference to `r4` and `r5`, unless something else is pointing to it besides `master`.

The first part of your question is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616957/how-do-you-roll-back-reset-a-git-repository-to-a-particular-commit), but I created this answer since you are asking  for a little more detail.

Comment: The easiest way to "keep" `r4` and `r5` is to do `git branch newbranch` before the `git reset` — `master` will be reset to point at `r3` but `newbranch` will keep pointing at `r5`.