# git, how to overwrite commits

Tags: git

I messed up my app and winded up doing a

```
git checkout <commit number>
```

to get back at the place where I would like to be.

when I do a git status, it says

```
 Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 5 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
```

I guess I'm on the 5th from my latest commit. Is there a way to make my 5th from latest commit my most recent one? pretty much to override or discard everything from my first four commits?

UPDATE.

I did a

```
git reset --hard <commit number>
```

but how can I push to my repository? it says...

```
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
```

I don't want to perform a merge, I pretty much want to wipe out my latest 4 commits

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you roll back (reset) a git repository to a particular commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616957/how-do-you-roll-back-reset-a-git-repository-to-a-particular-commit)

Comment: Ten years ago and I'm having the same question... the timelessness of git! thx!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always force a push with the `-f` option:

```
git push -f origin master
```

but of course beware because this *will* destroy history.

Also make sure to specify both remote and branch name because without it, by default git will try and force push *all* branches to the given (or upstream) remote.

Comment: such an easy fix! thx

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout ORIG_HEAD
```

should get you back to where you were after your most recent checkout.

If that doesn't help, you can also check out `git reflog`. It'll show you a list of your recent rebases, checkouts, etc., and you can find the SHA of the commit you want to get back to.

Comment: Don't forget co is an alias for checkout

Answer (score 1):

```
git reset --hard <commit number>
```

Comment: i resetted to my the version i want. but when i try doing git push, it says..

To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected. i pretty much want to erase the first 4 commits or undo everything