# Git - how to roll back all changes to last commit?

Tags: git, commit, revert

I accidently deleted source directory.. I thought I was deleting another directory. But I have last commit that is where I need to revert back.

I have two branches:

```
master
dev1
```

On dev1:

```
git add .
git commit -m 'commit message'
```

Then:

```
git checkout master
git merge dev1
```

Then I accidently deleted whole repository.

Then I hard reseted to last commit and I see it shows that all correct changes were made.
But when I got to my directory it is old directory (I copied old one, but it is not being deleted from here).
What Should I do?

Comment: You didn’t have to hard reset there; just `git checkout master -- path/to/folder`. What does `git status` say?

Comment: what do you mean by `delete the whole repository`?

Comment: @poke it says nothing to commit.

Comment: Last commit is only in another branch. If I have files that are from commit before last one. Can I somehow merge it so it would restore to newest one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you removed the whole repository, you'll have to get it back from a backup (or reconstruct it from any other repositories you pulled from, or pushed to). There isn't anything for git to work on anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Do a

> git log

to get the hash of the previous commit and then do a

> git revert your_hash_here

to revert the commit. Finally do a

> git push

to push your changes and fast forward them to master

Comment: I tried it, but it gives this error:
   `cb963f5..f37d6e4  new_medical_card_rev1 -> new_medical_card_rev1
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to '/home/oerp/openerp70/openerp/source/addons/ambulance_system'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "deleted the whole repository". From your comments on other answers I think you haven't deleted everything, and if you can still execute `git` commands in that directory successfully, you can simply `git reset --hard master` (which [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616957/how-do-you-roll-back-reset-a-git-repository-to-a-particular-commit) explains in more detail).

If you've completely hosed your entire git repository directory on the localhost, since you pushed your changes to remote, you can simply `git clone <example.com/myrepo.git>` and it will pull everything down from the remote.