# Bad pushes in git log

Tags: git, github

I am using git and there were some files pushed by another user over a space of a few commits, which should not have been pushed yet.  They are the most recent commits, and I can see in git log the last good commit that I would like to reset my local system to, and then push all local changes back so that the system is in a clean state again

How do I do this?  We are using a repo on github, if it makes any difference.

The intent afterwards is for that user to then do a pull, resolve conflicts locally, and henceforth be advised against pushing stuff that isn't ready to be pushed yet.  But of course, I need to get the cloud repo back to a good state first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you roll back (reset) a git repository to a particular commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616957/how-do-you-roll-back-reset-a-git-repository-to-a-particular-commit)

Comment: Duplicate of [Revert to previous Git commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-to-previous-git-commit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question "[How do you roll back (reset) a git repository to a particular commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1616957/6309)" is about using [`git reset --hard`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) to revert to a good commit.

But, "to get the cloud repo back to a good state", that will leave you with the only option of a `git push --force`, which can be inconvenient for other users accessing that same cloud repo: they will need to reset their own branch to the new (fetched) `origin/master` branch.

If you don't mind leaving those bad commits in the history, you could use [`git revert`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) in order to make one more commit (which would cancel said bad commits), and push (regular push) that extra commit.

You [can revert multiple commit that way, with `git revert` or a combination of `git reset --hard` and `git reset --soft`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1470452/6309).

Everyone accessing the remote repo would do a regular `git pull`, and see any modification introduced by the bad commits disappear.

Comment: The problem I have with doing a git reset --hard <SHA of last good version> is that when I push this, it rewrites the history of the repository.  I don't mind leaving the bad commits in the history, but I want the files to be restored to what they were previously.  The documentation on 'git revert' is unclear how I would use it to roll back changes from several commits, some of which could have been merges.

Comment: @markt1964 then I would recommend the reset --hard + reset --soft approach: very easy to do (at the end of http://stackoverflow.com/a/1470452/6309).