# How to set back to a specific commit in GH-Pages?

Tags: git, github, git-branch, github-pages

Ok, I followed this advice: `git reset --hard <tag/branch/commit id>` from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616957/how-do-you-roll-back-reset-a-git-repository-to-a-particular-commit)

And I got this message: `HEAD is now at ######## specific update`.

The issue is that this is at main branch? I was trying to do this to gh-pages.

How do I roll back to *that* specific commit *in* gh-pages?

Thanks

EDIT

Really puzzled by this, but just ran `git log` right now, and it's at where I chose to roll it back in gh-pages, but if I look at the output of the gh-pages, it's still the same, ie, not to the rollback version, if that makes any sense.

Super puzzled by this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do this (you should not mess with the history as soon as other people are involved to the project) you follow this flow:

- `git checkout gh-pages`
- `git reset --hard <commit hash>`
- `git push -f origin gh-pages`

The last one will force push your change to the Github remote and so it will be at your commit hash.

Comment: thank you! The last line helped to update the changes in gh-pages. No worries on messing the history of this project, as I'm the only person doing the commits. Thanks again!

Comment: Would I permanently loose my newer commits, after the hard reset?