# Can we say that a git revert merges the old previous commits on top of the reverted commit?

Tags: git, merge, clearcase, git-revert

I'm trying to wrap my head around `git revert`.

I'm coming from a [Clearcase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_ClearCase) background where to undo a bad commit, you would either:

1. check in the old versions of the files on top of the bad committed files (only file level commits on Clearcase)
2. Delete the element that was the commit
3. In the version tree, merge the previous version into the current version to create a new version that is identical to the one prior to the latest commit.

Now in my mind, a git revert is an automatic equivalent to the manual work in (3).

My question is: **Can we say that a git revert merges the old previous commits on top of the reverted commit?**

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166547/what-are-the-differences-between-revert-amend-rollback-and-undo-a-com/28166763#28166763

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In short**

`git revert` creates the inverse of the commit you want to undo. Then you commit that new change-set into the repository.

See section *Unmodifying a Modified File* in *[2.4 Git Basics - Undoing Things](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Undoing-Things)*.

So, no, you can't say:

> Can we say that a git revert merges the old previous commits on top of
>   the reverted commit?

because you can revert any commit in the history of the repository.

**Example**

Assume you have this history:

```
C1 <-- C2 <-- C3 (HEAD)
```

That means, if you want to revert commit `C2`, you don't commit the "old previous commit" which would be `C1`. Because then you'd end up with

```
C1 <-- C2 <-- C3 <-- C1 (HEAD)
```

which you don't. You end up with

```
C1 <-- C2 <-- C3 <-- C2' (HEAD)
```

with `C2'` being the inverse of `C2`, and `C3` still being part of your history.

**Illustration**

Here is an illustration of the above explanation, [taken from here](http://www.git-tower.com/learn/ebook/command-line/advanced-topics/undoing-things).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. `git revert` will create a new commit object for every commit you choose to revert, and each commit object will be the exact opposite of each commit you chose to revert respectively.

Meaning, if you `git revert C1`, then git will create `C1R` which exactly reverses all changes made by C1.

Comment: This is a great concise clear answer that captures the essence of the question with a minimum of words. (Sorry - the other guy had a diagram).

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that those ClearCase option are file by file.

[`git revert`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) works by commit (which is a bit like an UCM activity), meaning it will revert all the files referenced in that commit.

For reverting only a specific file, you have other options in "[Reset or revert a specific file to a specific revision using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/215718/6309)".

Comment: Thanks @VonC - always appreciate you bridging my clearcase->GIT knowledge