# Revert bad git clone

Tags: git

I've accidentally cloned (or pulled, I don't remember) another repo into my project repo, and now I see something like +1500 foreign commits, starting from year 2011. I don't know how to simply revert it, because these commits are braided into mine.

Good thing is I haven't pushed it yet, but I have some changes in my work which I would like to preserve. How can I do this?

---

@edit
The accepted answer doesn't preserve my work, but it can be simply solved by following these steps: move the modified files into some safe place → revert → move them back into reverted repo → make a new commit out of them.

Comment: check : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1625275/2142994

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you haven't made any other changes after that, you can follow this steps:

1. Run `git reflog`. This will give you a log of the actions done by you on the repo
2. Pick the log just before the pull. If it is the second last commit you can run

   `git reset --hard HEAD@{2}`

   to restore your repo to a state just before you pulled your repo