# How to rollback github repository to a previous commit?

Tags: git

How do I revert my Github Repository on Github to it's previous state?
I had made some change and committed them to github, but now I want to undo those changes on github. How would I do that?

I tried doing `git reset --hard 7727c5bfa99`
 but that ONLY changed the repository on my computer and not on the github website

Comment: if you commit again after the reset, github will reflect your local situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you roll back (reset) a Git repository to a particular commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616957/how-do-you-roll-back-reset-a-git-repository-to-a-particular-commit)

Comment: You need to update your remote.  That answer shows how to do so, after the reset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to push it.
git push -f origin master

Comment: A forced push can cause problems for others who might have already pulled those commits.  Another option would be to create a revert commit and push that up.

Answer (score 0):

After `git reset --hard 7727c5bfa99`, you just push the rolled back commit to remote repository(in this case Github repository), using `git push <reponame> -f`.