# GIT fix commits in local branch (and remote)

Tags: git

I have 2 branches with commits.

- Branch A and its commits is clean and was pushed to remote
- Branch B has commits from Branch A, but was pushed to remote as well

Branch B looks something like:

1. commit from Branch B
2. commit from Branch B
3. commit from Branch A
4. commit from Branch A
5. commit from Branch A
6. commit from Branch A
7. commit from Branch A

This happened because of a wrong rebase..

Before I make a merge request for Branch B I would like to fix it and remove all commits from Branch A.

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Do you mean that commit 7 is the newest and 1 is the oldest commit?

Comment: What should branch B look like instead?

Comment: I would like to remove commit 3-7 without changes in my code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you roll back (reset) a Git repository to a particular commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616957/how-do-you-roll-back-reset-a-git-repository-to-a-particular-commit) --> `git checkout <B>` and then `git reset --hard <2>` where you insert branch name `<B>` and commit hash of commit `<2>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git rebase -i HEAD~n`, Here `n` is the number of commit you want see in the bash and change them.

Steps(In your case) :

- `git rebase -i HEAD~7`
- Then simply replace the `pick` word with `drop` for commit's you want to delete from branch B
- Then save the bash file and exit.
- `git push --force-with-lease <remote> branch B` OR `git push -f <remote> branch B` it will push your lastest changes (without branch A's commit)